# New to PHP, need to ignore part of a variable in a function

Tags: php

So I'm attempting to concatenate two integers that form a whole serial number to verify if a user has the correct serial code. My second variable will always begin with P, how would I ignore the P from a user input while still having it appear in the concatenated variables in a function like this?

```php
$a = '1800';
$b = P100000000;

if ($a >= "1800" && $b >= "100000000") {
    echo "$a-$b is correct";
  } else {
      echo "I'm sorry, that serial does not match our system.";
}
```

Comment: Hint: See `substr()`

Comment: You're putting quotes around your integers and no quotes around your string. You have that backwards.

Comment: Is your PHP basic is clear???

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use `ltrim`.

```
if ($a >= "1800" && ltrim($b, 'P') >= "100000000") { ...
```

If the `P` isn't there for some reason, it won't remove anything.

Comment: I love trim answers, and if it could be any letter: `ltrim($b, 'A..Z')`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to remove all non-numeric characters from a string and convert it to an integer for comparison would be something like:

`intval( filter_var( $b, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT ) )`

the `filter_var` function returns a string, and the `intval` function returns the integer value from a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = 1800; // no quotes here for a number
$b = 'P100000000'; // quotes here please
$real_b = (int)substr($b,1); // cut the first letter, then cast to int

if ($a >= 1800 && $real_b >= 100000000) { // no quotes here for numbers or its a string
    echo "$a-$b is correct";
  } else {
      echo "I'm sorry, that serial does not match our system.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could also use regex if you have multiple non-digit beginning character;

```
<?php

$a = '1800';
$b = P100000000;

$b = preg_replace('/^\D/', '', $b);
print("${b}\n");
```